# Hangman game written in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, hangman

This collects user's guesses for the word. The user has 8 guesses, a correct guess and a repeated guess does not affect the guess count.

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    import string
    fullstring = string.ascii_lowercase
    lettersLeft = ''
    for letter in fullstring:
        if letter not in lettersGuessed:
            lettersLeft = lettersLeft + letter
    return lettersLeft

def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
    wordGuessed = ''
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            wordGuessed = wordGuessed + letter
        else:
            wordGuessed = wordGuessed + '_ '
    return wordGuessed

def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    numCorrect = 0
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            numCorrect += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

def hangman(secretWord):
    guessesLeft = 8
    lettersGuessed =[]

    print('Welcome to the game Hangman!')
    print('I am thinking of a word that is ' + str(len(secretWord)) + ' letters long.' )
    print('-----------')

    while guessesLeft > 0:
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            return print('Congratulations, you won!')
        print('You have ' + str(guessesLeft) + ' guesses left.')
        print('Available Letters: ' + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
        user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ')
        user_input = str(user_input)
        user_input = user_input.lower()

        if user_input not in lettersGuessed:
            lettersGuessed.append(user_input)

            if user_input in secretWord:
                print("Good guess: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                print('-----------')
            else:
                print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                print('-----------')
                guessesLeft -= 1
        else:
            print("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            print('-----------')

    return print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was " + str(secretWord))

hangman('stackoverflow')
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run as-is.  How are you intending to execute this?  `python hangman.py`?

Comment: you just call the function on a word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Multiple [PEP8 Style Violations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)***

There's a bunch of style violations here, and it really irks me.  You are also violating fundamental parts of Python syntax with some of these things, especially with indentation, so you should try and correct style issues as well as my other concerns/suggestions.  I try not harping on style, but there's enough issues here that it irks me enough to put this first.

- `import` statements must be at the beginning of the file.
- Function definitions need to be padded by ***two*** line breaks.  That is, from the end fo one function to the start of the next, you need two blank lines between them (except inside a Class definition, which you don't have here).
- Function names should be all lowercase, and multiple-word names for functions should be lowercase and separated with underscores (`getGuessedWord` should be `get_guessed_word`, etc.)
- Variable names should be all lowercase, not CamelCase.  (The exception are module-wide constants, which should be in all CAPS.).  Multi-word variable names (such as `lettersGuessed`) should be lowercase and separated with underscores (`letters_guessed`)
- Docstrings should be triple-quoted, not triple-apostrophe'd.  (`"""`, not `'''`)
- You have indentation problems that make your code error out in certain cases under `hangman` where you will have unexpected indentation. (note that I suppress these when testing code here for review, but it's a critical issue).  Use 100% consistent indentation - this should be 4 spaces per indentation level, not tabs, and you should not have some lines indented where they are not supposed to be.

---

***User input can be condensed to one line***

You currently use this for getting user input:

```
user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ')
user_input = str(user_input)
user_input = user_input.lower()
```

This can be condensed into one line, and we can also trim off the line break at the end too (so later recommendations for validation work without much issue):

```
user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ').lower().strip('\r\n')
```

---

***No checking for valid inputs***

You are expecting only letters to be provided, correct?  That's the basis of Hangman.

We should probably *test* to see if we're actually getting letters provided to us, and make a warning.  So, let's do this right after the user enters input:

```
user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ')).lower().strip('\r\n')
while user_input not in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print("You have not provided a letter, please only use letters!")
    user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ').lower().strip('\r\n')
```

---

***Output messages: Code repetition***

You've got this in here three times:

```
print('-----------')
```

You can instead use only one of these, and place it after the `if`/`else` block, and thereby not have to repeat this three times in a row inside the `if` block (note that I've snipped out all other contents of the `if`/`else` block, to shorten this post slightly).

```
if user_input not in letters_guessed:
    ....
else:
    ....

print('-----------')
```

---

***Use augmented assignment statements.***

This is currently in your code in `getGuessedWord`:

```
if letter in letters_guessed:
    word_guessed = word_guessed + letter
else:
    word_guessed = word_guessed + '_ '
```

Two things here: both of these can be condensed using augmented assignment statements, and you may wish to just use underscores without extra spaces between characters in the word, because it looks messy when I have some letters guessed and others not guessed (inconsistent spacing in output):

```
if letter in letters_guessed:
    word_guessed += letter
else:
    word_guessed += '_'
```

---

***Use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to define what to execute when script is called from command line***

`python3 hangman.py` will call hangman("stackoverflow"), but this is not really a good way to achieve it.

We should primarily define something like this at the end of the program to make sure that what runs is what we want to run when this is executed at the command line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hangman('stackoverflow')
```

Note though that you are always going to have "stackoverflow" as the string; you should strongly consider providing a file with valid words for usage, and then random selection therein rather than using a static string as an assignment.

> This has an added benefit of 'guarding' the call to `hangman()` (which is the replacement for a call to `main()` as some would have) if, for some reason, I was importing parts of the module and importing into another one.  This is more or less, also, a personal preference to guard whether I plan on importing or not, it's something I do regardless, just to protect calls to 'start' the program/script.

---

***Unnecessary creation of variables***

In `get_available_letters`, you do this:

```
fullstring = string.ascii_lowercase
....
for letter in fullstring:
```

Why do we create `fullstring` here?  It's not needed - we can just use this instead and not have to create the `fullstring` variable:

```
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
```

Comment: This is my suggestions after my first look at your code - this may expand a little more as I keep looking at it

Comment: thank you very much!! But while I understand that the  " if __name__ == ... " portion of the code checks if you're in main or importing the code from a module. I don't understand why it's necessary or an improvement. Could you explain, please?

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu Mainly as a guard to the call of `hangman()`, if for instance I were to be calling `hangman.py` from something called `game.py` or similar, or importing parts here into other modules/scripts.  Ultimately not needed if you only plan on running `hangman.py`, but my opinion is it's better to 'guard' that call than to not guard the call.

Answer (score 5):

Lurking today. I just post this for your pleasure. It might give you some ideas about condensing your code.

---

**Comments**

In python there is something called annotations, they are very use full. The let you define for yourself and other readers of the code what in parameters and return parameters function has.

**Example**

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
```

compared to

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord: str, lettersGuessed: list) -> str:
    ...
```

without the much expressive comment is that you wast a lot of space and make your code more hard to read. Of curse you should comment your code, but you don't have to comment on what the names of the function, secretWord, lettersGussed already states. But we don't know what type the parameters is from the names, but annotations can do that.

Comments should contain information on not told by the naming or annotation. **Don't repeat yourself** applies to comments as well.

---

**Operators**

This function

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in 

    lettersGuessed;
          False otherwise
        '''
        numCorrect = 0
        for letter in secretWord:
            if letter in lettersGuessed:
                numCorrect += 1
            else:
                return False
        return True
```

is equivalent to the all operator like this:

```
all(l in guesses_letters for l in secret)
```

If you put a statement like this as is in a function, you are repeating your self. In the same sense that

```
def is_even(number):
   return number % 2 == 0:
```

is repeating what the statement already states.

---

Whenever you are dealing with user input which needs have to follow certain rules, it will always makes sense to separate it from other parts of the code like putting it in a function.

So by my interpretation of your code in which I started with your code, with out being as nice as you are, would be this.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase


def get_user_guess(guesses_letters: set) -> str:
    user_input = ""
    while user_input not in ascii_lowercase or len(user_input)-1:
        user_input = input("Guess Letter -> ")
        if user_input in guesses_letters:
            user_input = ""
    return user_input


def show(secret: str, guessed_letters: set):
    for l in secret:
        print(" {} ".format(l if l in guessed_letters else "_"), end="")
    print()


def hangman(secret: str):
    guesses = 8
    guesses_letters = set()

    while guesses and not all(l in guesses_letters for l in secret):
        c = get_user_guess(guesses_letters)
        guesses_letters.add(c)
        guesses -= 0 if c in secret else 1
        print("Guesses left {}".format(guesses))
        show(secret, guesses_letters)


def main():
    secret_word = "stackoverflow"
    hangman(secret_word)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Now why am I wining about don't repeat yourself? It is with this in mind:

> "Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous,
>   authoritative representation within a system"

this principal when coding will make your life easier, and readers life easier as well.

Comment: This is not really an answer, please comment on which points your code improves on the posted one.

Comment: Yes it was an answer. But I agree that I could have been explicit.

Comment: @Simon It looks real good now. Sure upvote from me for all the info

Answer (score 2):

It is very good that you separated your logic from your user interface so it can more easily be improved.

Adding tests makes simplifying even easier and they also double as documentation so adding tests was the first thing I did.

Afterwards I proceeded re-implementing your functions by making use of the numerous python built-ins and [comprehensions](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) to reflect the meaning on a more abstract level avoiding re-inventing the wheel.

#### `getAvailableLetters`

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.

    >>> getAvailableLetters("acz")
    'bdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy'
    '''
    return ''.join(sorted(set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set(lettersGuessed)))
```

Here I used the `set` built-in that mimics a mathematical set. Subtraction between two sets A and B means all the element of A not in B. I then use `sorted` to restore order as sets are un-ordered and `join` the result back into a string.

#### `getGuessedWord`

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.

    >>> getGuessedWord("cattle", "at")
    '_ a t t _ _ '
    '''
    return ' '.join(char if char in lettersGuessed else '_' for char in secretWord) + ' '
```

I decided to also fix the un-even spacing as mentioned in another review. This is a use of a ternary conditional expression inside a generator comprehension. It is very simple and short.

#### `isWordGuessed`

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise

    >>> isWordGuessed("foobar", "broaf")
    True
    >>> isWordGuessed("foobar", "x")
    False
    '''
    return all(letter in secretWord for letter in lettersGuessed)
```

How would you express this in English? A `secretWord` is guessed if `all` of its letters are contained `in` the `lettersGuessed`. The code resembles really closely this "high-level" description and is thus very readable.